# Zend Framework2 : Post is not working correctly

Tags: php, forms, zend-framework2

I am a Zend Framework beginner.
I guess My question is very basic... but I can't solve it by myself.

In **indexAction**, **$request->isPost()** is always false.
What is happening?

**EntryController::indexAction**

```
public function indexAction() {
    $form = new AgreementForm();
    $form->get('submit')->setValue('Go Entry Form');
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        var_dump('//// $request->isPost() is true //////');
        if ($form->get('agreementCheck')) {
            // Redirect to list of entries
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('entry');
        } else {
            return array('form' => $form);
        }
    } else {
        var_dump('//// $request->isPost() is false //////');
        return array('form' => $form);
    }
}
```

**form in index.phtml**

```
<?php
$form = $this->form;
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('entry', array('action' => 'index')));
$form->prepare();
echo $this->form()->openTag($form);
echo $this->formCheckbox($form->get('agreementCheck'));
echo $this->formSubmit($form->get('submit'));
echo $this->form()->closeTag();
?>
```

**AgreementForm** is generated using code generator.
http://zend-form-generator.123easywebsites.com/formgen/create
as below.

```
class AgreementForm extends Form {

    public function __construct($name = null) {
        parent::__construct('');

        $this->setAttribute('method', 'post');

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'agreementCheck',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\MultiCheckbox',
            'attributes' => array(
                'required' => 'required',
                'value' => '0',
            ),
            'options' => array(
                'label' => 'Checkboxes Label',
                'value_options' => array(
                    '0' => 'Checkbox',
                ),
            ),
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'csrf',
            'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
        ));

        $this->add(array(
            'name' => 'submit',
            'attributes' => array(
                'type' => 'submit',
                'value' => 'Go',
                'id' => 'submitbutton',
            ),
        ));
    }
}
```

Please tell me some hints.

**update:**
In the result of analysis by Developer Tools, POST and GET works at the same time.
[image]

**update:**
router definition @module.config.php is this.

```
'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'entry' => array(
                'type' => 'segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/entry[/][:action][/:id]',
                    'constraints' => array(
                        'action' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                        'id' => '[0-9]+',
                    ),
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Entry\Controller\Entry',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'home' => array(
                'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Literal',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Entry\Controller\Entry',
                        'action' => 'index',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: check your HTML source to ensure the form method is POST and check the HTTP method after submitting with Firebug/Chrome debugger.

Comment: @BramGerritsen I make sure that form method is POST. But when submitting it, at the same time, Get method is runnning... By the way, index.phtml is defined as home in module.config.php

Comment: I wanna see your routes i.e module.config.php

Comment: @noobie-php Thank you for comment. I added router setting.

Comment: May i ask what exactly the EXPECTED result and what the CURRENT result is? Because no matter what, you'll always end up with a Form being displayed! In success-case without data, on Failure case without

Comment: @Sam Thank you for comment. EXPECTED result is $request->isPost() == true after submitting AgreementForm. CURRENT result is $request->isPost() == false.

Comment: How do you verify this? Did you Debug? Because the `else` of your `form->get('agr..')` would have the same result.

Comment: @Sam updated code. It returns //// $request->isPost() is false ////// even if after submitting.

Comment: Can you verify that the HTML of the FORM itself, is posting using "POST" to your expected URL?

Comment: @Jagie, Could you try removing the line with `setAttribute('action')` to make sure you are posting to the exact same page? In your development tools you see a 302 redirect from the POST to the GET happening, so I think the url helper is not returning the right uri.

Comment: @BramGerritsen, the 302 is the reason i asked for his routes

Comment: @Jagie: try to replace 'route' => '/entry[/][:action][/:id]' with 'route' => 'entry/entry[/][:action][/:id]' and then check your request

Answer (score 1):

A few things are wrong:

1. In the form class you add a csrf element, but you don't render it in the view. This will cause a validation error. So you need to add this to your view:

   echo $this->formHidden($form->get('csrf'));
2. You're adding a Multicheckbox element to the form, but in your view you're using the formCheckbox view helper to render it. If you really want a Multicheckbox then you should render it with the formMultiCheckbox helper:

   echo $this->formMultiCheckbox($form->get('agreementCheck'));

After these changes it should work.

Edit: Also you may want to pass a name to the form constructor:

```
parent::__construct('agreementform');
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried following your answer but situation did not  change. POST and GET method works at the same time when submitting. I guess this is the problem.

Comment: I think the problem is in the form action. Check the rendered html of the form and in particular the form action attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you do not need to explicitly say

```
$form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('entry', array('action' => 'index')));
```

Omit that line, and see what happens.